# Sqlite- Updating existing table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to update `sqlite` Table using `execSQL`. But, After executing it is clearing(empty) my whole table data instead of updating certain fields. My code is

```
private void updatedata(String name,String spingender,String cWeight,String spinunit,String htInString,String spingoal,String spinactivity,String spinexercise,String scalorie,String sprotein,String carbohydrate,String sfat) {

        DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        System.out.println("in update data "+name + spingender + cWeight);
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE name ='"+name+"'";
        Cursor QueryCursor = db.rawQuery(Query,null);

        // there is some record available in the cursor 
        if (QueryCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 db.execSQL("UPDATE login SET gender='"+spingender+"',weight='"+cWeight+"',userunit='"+spinunit+"',height='"+htInString+"',goal='"+spingoal+"',activeness='"+spinactivity+"',exercise='"+spinexercise+"',calorie='"+scalorie+"',fat='"+sfat+"',carbohydrate='"+carbohydrate+"',protein='"+sprotein+"'");            
        }

        QueryCursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

> ***full code***

```
package com.bharatwellness.mainactivities;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.bharatwellness.libraries.DatabaseHandler;
import com.bharatwellness.libraries.UserFunctions;
import com.project.homepagedemo.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfilePageActivity extends Activity{

    private String gender;
    private String weight;
    private String height;
    private EditText etWeight;
    private EditText etHeightFirst;
    private EditText etHeighttwo;
    private Button takePhoto;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1313;    
    private String image_str;
    private String goal;
    private String activeness;
    private String exercise;
    private double double_height;
    private TextView updateButton;
    private String name;
    private String htInString ;
    private Spinner spinnergender;
    private Spinner spinnergoal;
    private Spinner spinneractiveness;
    private Spinner spinnerexercise;
    private String userunit;
    private Spinner spinnerunit;

    private String spinunit;
    private String spingender;
    private String spingoal;
    private String spinactivity;
    private String spinexercise;

    private String[] KUnits = { "Kgs", "Pounds" };
    private String[] PUnits = { "Pounds","Kgs" };

    private String[] MGenders = { "Male", "Female" };
    private String[] FGenders = { "Female", "Male" };

    private String[] RGoals = {"Reduce Weight","Maintain Weight","Gain Weight"};
    private String[] MGoals = {"Maintain Weight","Reduce Weight","Gain Weight"};
    private String[] GGoals = {"Gain Weight","Maintain Weight","Reduce Weight"};

    private String[] HActiveness = {"Highly Active","Moderate Activity","Low Active"};
    private String[] MActiveness = {"Moderate Activity","Highly Active","Low Active"};
    private String[] LActiveness = {"Low Active","Moderate Activity","Highly Active"};

    private String[] LExerciseLevel = {"Less than 30 Mins","30 - 60 Mins","More than 60 Mins"};
    private String[] RExerciseLevel = {"30 - 60 Mins","Less than 30 Mins","More than 60 Mins"};
    private String[] MExerciseLevel = {"More than 60 Mins","30 - 60 Mins","Less than 30 Mins"};
    private String age;
    private double valueaftergoal;
    private double recxa;
    private double recxb;
    private double finalcalorie;
    private double protein;
    private double carbs;
    private double fat;
    private String scalorie;
    private String sprotein;
    private String sfat;
    private String carbohydrate;
    private String cWeight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            name = bundle.getString("name");
            System.out.println("in profile" + name);
        }


        etWeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        etHeightFirst = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHeightFeet);
        etHeighttwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHeightInches);
        spinnerunit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerweight);
        spinnergender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnergender);
        spinnergoal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnergoal);
        spinneractiveness = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinneractiveness);
        spinnerexercise = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerexercise);
        takePhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.picbutton);
        updateButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());




        selectData();
        genderselected();
        unitselected();
        goalselected();
        activityselected();
        exerciseselected();



        //height
        double doubleHeightValue = Double.parseDouble(height);
        System.out.println("dble ht value " + doubleHeightValue);
        double doubleHeightInCM = doubleHeightValue * 2.54;
        System.out.println("ht in CM " + doubleHeightInCM);
        double_height = doubleHeightInCM * 0.3937008;
        System.out.println("ht to feet " + double_height);
        int height_in_feet = (int) (double_height / 12);
        System.out.println("height_in_feet " + height_in_feet);
        int height_in_inch = (int) (double_height % 12);
        System.out.println("height_in_inch " + height_in_inch);

        etWeight.setText("" + weight);
        etHeightFirst.setText("" + height_in_feet);
        etHeighttwo.setText("" + height_in_inch );

        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String  f = etHeightFirst.getText().toString();
                String i = etHeighttwo.getText().toString();
                cWeight = etWeight.getText().toString();

                int feet = Integer.parseInt(f);
                int ifeet = Integer.parseInt(i);
                int newHeight = (feet * 12) + ifeet;
                htInString = String.valueOf(newHeight);
                System.out.println("name" + name + htInString);

                spinunit = (String) spinnerunit.getSelectedItem();
                spingender = (String) spinnergender.getSelectedItem();
                spingoal = (String) spinnergoal.getSelectedItem();
                spinactivity = (String) spinneractiveness.getSelectedItem();
                spinexercise = (String) spinnerexercise.getSelectedItem();

                calculations();

                scalorie = Double.toString(finalcalorie);
                sfat = Double.toString(fat);
                sprotein = Double.toString(protein);
                carbohydrate = Double.toString(carbs);

                System.out.println("Gender on item selected" + spingender);
                System.out.println("Exercise on item selected" + spinexercise);
                System.out.println("Goal on item selected" + spingoal);
                System.out.println("Exercise on item selected" + spinexercise);
                System.out.println("Activity on item selected" + spinactivity);
                updatedata(name,spingender,cWeight,spinunit,htInString,spingoal,spinactivity,spinexercise,scalorie,sprotein,carbohydrate,sfat);
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.updateUser(name,spingender,cWeight,spinunit,htInString,spingoal,spinactivity,spinexercise,scalorie,sprotein,carbohydrate,sfat);
                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalorieMainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

    class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camintent,CAM_REQUEST);

        }

    }


    private void selectData() {

        DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT gender,weight,height,goal,activeness,exercise,userunit,userage FROM login";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        // there is some record available in the cursor 
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                gender = cursor.getString(0);
                weight = cursor.getString(1);
                height = cursor.getString(2);
                goal = cursor.getString(3);
                activeness = cursor.getString(4);
                exercise = cursor.getString(5);
                userunit = cursor.getString(6);
                age = cursor.getString(7);

                Log.e("calorie info", "gender:" + gender + ", weight:" + weight+ ",unit:" + userunit + ", height:" + height + ", goal:" + goal+ ", activeness:" + activeness+ ", exercise:" + exercise + ", age :" + age);

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        cursor.close();

        db.close();
    }

    public void gotoCalorieHomeActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,CalorieMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void genderselected(){
        if(gender.equals("Male")){
            //gender
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_gender = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MGenders);
            adapter_gender
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnergender.setAdapter(adapter_gender);
            //spinnergender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
        else{
            //gender
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_gender = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, FGenders);
            adapter_gender
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnergender.setAdapter(adapter_gender);
            //spinnergender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
    public void unitselected(){

        //for units
        if(userunit.equals("Kgs")){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_unit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, KUnits);
            adapter_unit
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerunit.setAdapter(adapter_unit);
            //spinnerunit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
        else{

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_unit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, PUnits);
            adapter_unit
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerunit.setAdapter(adapter_unit);
            //spinnerunit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
    public void goalselected(){
        if(goal.equals("Reduce Weight")){

            //goal
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_goal = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, RGoals);
            adapter_goal
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnergoal.setAdapter(adapter_goal);
            //spinnergoal.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        else if(goal.equals("Maintain Weight")){

            //goal
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_goal = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MGoals);
            adapter_goal
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnergoal.setAdapter(adapter_goal);
            //spinnergoal.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
        else{
            //goal
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_goal = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, GGoals);
            adapter_goal
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnergoal.setAdapter(adapter_goal);
            //spinnergoal.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
    }

    public void activityselected()
    {
        if(activeness.equals("Highly Active")){
            //activeness
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_activeness = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, HActiveness);
            adapter_activeness
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinneractiveness.setAdapter(adapter_activeness);
        //  spinneractiveness.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
        else if(activeness.equals("Moderate Activity")){
            //activeness
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_activeness = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MActiveness);
            adapter_activeness
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinneractiveness.setAdapter(adapter_activeness);
            //spinneractiveness.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        }
        else{
            //activeness
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_activeness = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LActiveness);
            adapter_activeness
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinneractiveness.setAdapter(adapter_activeness);
            //spinneractiveness.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        }
    }

    public void exerciseselected(){
        if (exercise.equals("Less than 30 Mins")){
            //exercise
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exercise = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LExerciseLevel);
            adapter_exercise
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerexercise.setAdapter(adapter_exercise);
        //spinnerexercise.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        else if(exercise.equals("30 - 60 Mins")){
            //exercise
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exercise = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, RExerciseLevel);
            adapter_exercise
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerexercise.setAdapter(adapter_exercise);
        //  spinnerexercise.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        else{
            //exercise
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exercise = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MExerciseLevel);
            adapter_exercise
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerexercise.setAdapter(adapter_exercise);
        //  spinnerexercise.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void calculations() {
        //weight conversion
        Double dweight = Double.parseDouble(weight);
        System.out.println("weight in calculations"+weight);

        if(spinunit.equals("Kgs") ){
            dweight =  dweight * 2.20462;

        }
        else {


        }

        //height conversion

        int iheight = Integer.parseInt(htInString);
        System.out.println("height in calculations"+htInString);
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity height" + iheight);

        //age conversion
        int iage = Integer.parseInt(age);
        System.out.println("age in calculations"+age);
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity age" + iage);

        //calculating goal
        if(spingender.equals("Female")){
            valueaftergoal = 655 + (4.3 * dweight) + (4.7 * iheight) - (4.7 * iage);
            System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity valueaftergoal" + valueaftergoal);
        }
        else {

            valueaftergoal = 66 + (6.3 * dweight) + (12.9 * iheight) - (6.8 * iage);
            System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity valueaftergoal" + valueaftergoal);
        }

        if(spingoal.equals("Reduce Weight") || spingoal.equals("Maintain Weight") || spingoal.equals("Gain Weight") ){
            if(spinactivity.equals("Highly Active") && spinexercise.equals("Less than 30 Mins") ){
                recxa = (1.10 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.00 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);

            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Highly Active") && spinexercise.equals("30 - 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.10 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.05 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Highly Active") && spinexercise.equals("More than 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.10 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.10 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Moderate Activity") && spinexercise.equals("Less than 30 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.05 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.00 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Moderate Activity") && spinexercise.equals("30 - 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.05 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.05 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Moderate Activity") && spinexercise.equals("More than 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.05 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.10 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Low Active") && spinexercise.equals("Less than 30 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.00 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.00 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Low Active") && spinexercise.equals("30 - 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.00 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.05 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else if(spinactivity.equals("Low Active") && spinexercise.equals("More than 60 Mins")){
                recxa = (1.00 * valueaftergoal);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxa" +recxa);

                recxb = (1.10 * recxa);
                System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity recxb" +recxb);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("None");
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("None weight or goal");
        }

        if(spingoal.equals("Reduce Weight")){

            finalcalorie = recxb * 0.9;
            System.out.println("Final" + finalcalorie);
        }
        else if(spingoal.equals("Maintain Weight")){
            finalcalorie = recxb;
            System.out.println("Final" + finalcalorie);
        }
        else if(spingoal.equals("Gain Weight")){
            finalcalorie = 1.2 * recxb;
            System.out.println("Final" + finalcalorie);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("None found");
        }


        protein = ((finalcalorie * 50) / 100 ) / 4 ;
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity protein" + protein);

        carbs = ((finalcalorie * 30) / 100 ) / 4 ;
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity carbs" + carbs);

        fat = ((finalcalorie * 20) / 100 ) / 9 ;
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity fat" + fat);

        finalcalorie = Math.round(finalcalorie * 100);
        finalcalorie = finalcalorie/100;
        System.out.println("this is the part of calculation in disease activity finalcalorie" + finalcalorie);

        protein = Math.round(protein * 100);
        protein = protein/100;
        System.out.println("This is the value of " + protein);

        carbs = Math.round(carbs * 100);
        carbs = carbs/100;
        System.out.println("This is the value of " + carbs);

        fat = Math.round(fat * 100);
        fat = fat/100;
        System.out.println("This is the value of " + fat);



    }
    private void updatedata(String name,String spingender,String cWeight,String spinunit,String htInString,String spingoal,String spinactivity,String spinexercise,String scalorie,String sprotein,String carbohydrate,String sfat) {

        DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println("in update data "+name + spingender + cWeight);
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE name ='"+name+"'";
        Cursor QueryCursor = db.rawQuery(Query,null);

        // there is some record available in the cursor 
        if (QueryCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 db.execSQL("UPDATE login SET gender='"+spingender+"',weight='"+cWeight+"',userunit='"+spinunit+"',height='"+htInString+"',goal='"+spingoal+"',activeness='"+spinactivity+"',exercise='"+spinexercise+"',calorie='"+scalorie+"',fat='"+sfat+"',carbohydrate='"+carbohydrate+"',protein='"+sprotein+"' WHERE name ='"+name+"'");         
        }

        QueryCursor.close();
        db.close();
    }




}
```

Comment: You're updating **ALL THE RECORDS**, since you don't use a `WHERE` condition in your `UPDATE` command.

Comment: tried with where clause after reading your comments. Same thing happening.

Comment: What is the use of selected record in updatedata() method exactly?

Comment: are you continously dropping and recreating your table?

Comment: @MousaJafari - Actually i got one link regarding this and he said to use select data before updating.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example

Comment: But it seems so. It seems that when you create your databaseHandler object, you use a **"CREATE TABLE"** instead of a **"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For update you need to use    `db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)`

but you are using

`db.execSQL("UPDATE login SET gender='"+spingender+"',weight='"+cWeight+"',userunit='"+spinunit+"',height='"+htInString+"',goal='"+spingoal+"',activeness='"+spinactivity+"',exercise='"+spinexercise+"',calorie='"+scalorie+"',fat='"+sfat+"',carbohydrate='"+carbohydrate+"',protein='"+sprotein+"'");`

So its not `updating` your table rather its `executing` new ..

So you should  take care of this

Check Code :

//  WITH 3 PARAMETER.. yOU CAN ADD AS YOUR REQUIREMENT

```
public void  updatedata(String name ,String spingender ,String cWeight)

    {
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
// Assign values for each row.  
// USERNAME is COLUMN NAME of you table ,
// name is your value you are passing 

        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", name);
        updatedValues.put("GENDER", spingender);
        updatedValues.put("wEIGHT", cWeight);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";

        db.update("yor tablename " , updatedValues, where, new String[]{name});     

    }
```

Now you can `update` your table with new `spingender` and `cWeight` as `username` :)

Comment: i tried this way also ! Same thing is happening. My table is getting empty !

Comment: again same thing ma'am . I guess i am doing something wrong in database handler. Can i post that too so that you can judge my mistake ?

Comment: Yes just upadte your question with proper code and all required code

Comment: It worked ! Issue was with create table! It was creating all my tables again while updating.

Comment: I wrote in firstline that you are using execution query not update query so you are facing the issues.. any ways Its my gudness that you got the solution :)

Comment: yes .. thank you :) 
I want your more help on notification part. Have you worked on it ?

Comment: I want to notify user 3 times a day on particular time regarding breakfast,lunch and dinner.

Comment: you have to go for alarm manager and set the time , after 1nce alaram start in receiverclass start notification..Note:   use BroadcastReceiver to capture the alarm manager events and start a notification

Comment: Also, if user close the application then what will happen to the notification ? It is necessary to keep the app running?

Comment: No .. In background it will start 1nce broadcastreciver got alaram

Answer (score 3):

First you should use `getWritableDatabase()` instead of `getReadableDatabase()` to make changes on table records and use "WHERE" statement in your query.
Why you don't use `db.update()` instead?

Comment: corrected it. But it is not updating table. It is deleting all the records instead!

Answer (score 2):

Try to update particular record with `name` in `updatedata(...)`

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put("gender", spingender);
  values.put("Weight", cWeight);
  values.put("userunit", spinunit);
  values.put("height", htInString);
  values.put("goal", spingoal);
  values.put("activeness", spinactivity);
  values.put("exercise", spinexercise);
  values.put("calorie", scalorie);
  values.put("fat", sfat);
  values.put("carbohydrate", carbohydrate);
  values.put("protein", sprotein);


  String whereClause =" name=? ";
  String[] whereArgs = new String[]{name};

  int rows = db.update("login", values, whereClause, whereArgs);

  if(rows > 0){
  //Update successfully
  }
```

Comment: @pratz9999 Issue is some where else. If you need more help then provide your all code  properly.

Comment: added ! Please check !

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to update the row of the table but you didn't specify which row you are trying to update. Specify the row you wanted to update by using "WHERE" clause.

Comment: if (QueryCursor.moveToFirst()) --- remove this.. and try... and tell